# What are hidden partitions on a Samsung laptop for?

Tags: windows, partitioning, filesystems, multi-boot

I have just found two hidden partitions on my Samsung laptop running Windows 7:

```
File System          Label             Size       Flags
ntfs                 SYSTEM            100Mb      boot
%hidden partition 1%
%hidden partition 2%
ntfs                 SAMSUNG_REC       21Gb       diag
```

**Q1:** What are they for?

**Q2:** Is it safe to delete them?

**Q3:** Is it ok to format `%hidden partiton x%` and reinstall Windows 7 and install Ubuntu after that to have a dual-boot system?

Comment: What generated the output you quoted (it looks like `parted`, but I can't be sure of that), and did that program really generate the text `%hidden partition 1%` and `%hidden partition 2%`? It's important to identify what program generated output and to reproduce it *completely* and *accurately* for diagnoses like this. Generally speaking, I wouldn't recommend deleting any partition; but if you need to shrink one to make room for Linux, do so. Making backups first is always advisable.

Comment: If you are OK with losing everything on the hard disk, you can wipe it out entirely (losing even the partition information) and create a fresh ntfs partition about half of the total disk space (_you can do so during Windows setup_). Install Windows first on this, then Ubuntu on the unpartitioned space (_Ubuntu will create required partitions automatically_). (This is different from reclaiming existing partitions for reuse, which isn't always necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SYSTEM partition contains boot files and is automatically generated upon installing Windows. So it is not recommended to remove this partition.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/can-i-delete-the-system-reserved-partition-from/656014d2-a516-46e6-a841-d0f9333ecb48

The SAMSUNG_REC partition appears to be a recovery partition to restore your Samsung laptop to factory conditions. This could be removed if you no longer want a backup inside your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! And is it ok to remove SYSTEM if I do not need any Windows OS anymore?

Comment: Prob not recommended to remove recovery partition. If OP is wondering what they are, most likely OP will need it down the road when something goes bad. ;)

Comment: The `SYSTEM` partition looks like it may be an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which you should not remove if you want the disk to be bootable on an EFI system. If you're hung up on deleting partitions because of the 4-partition limit, be aware that it applies only to MBR disks. You may have a GPT disk, though, which doesn't suffer from this limit. The *complete* `parted` output will tell us which partition table type you've got.